# access attributes of objects stored in lists

Tags: r, list, object, attributes, lapply

I store many objects (e.g. htest or lm) in a list. I would like to access the attributes (like p-values) of each object stored in this list.

I can access one attribute using `l[[1]]$p.value`. Is there a solution and access all attributes of one kind and store them in a vector using sapply or something similar?

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = runif(n = 100),
                   x2 = runif(n = 100),
                   x3 = sample(x = c(0,1), size = 100, replace = T))  

l <- list()

for(i in 1:2){
    l[[i]] <- t.test(data[,i] ~ data[,3])
}    

l[[1]]$p.value
```

Comment: You can check the `str(l)` and get the attributes that you need. From the list, `sapply(l, function(x) x$p.value)` gets the p.value

Comment: Use lapply with the function "[" followed by a number, the number is the that of the attribute.  For example, lapply(l,"[",3) gives each of the p values.  You can also use sapply.  Hope I've understood your question.

Comment: For the record, most components of the `t.test` return are not *attributes* in the *R*-sense. Components of the results are named, e.g., statistic, parameter, p.value, etc, and they are merely list elements. Some of those list elements have attributes themselves (e.g., the names of named vectors), which you would access via something like `attributes(l[[1]]$statistic)`. @user1945827's comment can also be done with `sapply` and/or using `[[` if you want to neck the response down to simpler vectors.